# Understanding Hamiltonian Path, NP vs Co-NP

Tags: np, nondeterminism, co-np

I am having difficulty understanding the distinction between NP and Co-NP.

According to my textbook (Sipser), the HAMPATH problem is in NP. That is, for the language: 
*HAMPATH = { (G,s,t) | G is a directed graph with a Hamiltonian path from s to t}*, there exists a nondeterministic Turing Machine *M* that can decide this problem in polynomial time. I understood this to mean that for some input *(G,s,t)*, *M* accepts if G has a Hamiltonian Path from s to t, and *M* rejects if G does not have a Hamiltonian Path from s to t, both in polynomial time.

However, the book also says that *!HAMPATH =  { (G,s,t) | G is a directed graph with no Hamiltonian path from s to t}* is in Co-NP, so it is not known to be in NP.

Why couldn't the same NTM for HAMPATH be used to decide !HAMPATH, except that it returns the opposite state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nondeterministic Turing machine is perhaps more clearly viewed as a Turing machine with two inputs: one is the actual input, in your case $\langle G,s,t \rangle$, and the other a polynomial size "witness", in your case a purported Hamiltonian path $p$. The machine checks, in polynomial time, that $p$ is indeed a Hamiltonian path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$, and if so, accepts; otherwise it rejects.

In what sense does this machine $M$ nondeterministically accept $\mathsf{HAMPATH}$?

- If $\langle G,s,t \rangle \in \mathsf{HAMPATH}$ then there exists a witness $p$ such that $M(\langle G,s,t \rangle,p)$ accepts.
- If $\langle G,s,t \rangle \notin \mathsf{HAMPATH}$ then $M(\langle G,s,t \rangle,p)$ rejects for *all* values of $p$.

Now consider the machine $!M$ which accepts when $M$ rejects and rejects when $M$ accepts.

- If $\langle G,s,t \rangle \in \mathsf{!HAMPATH}$ then $!M(\langle G,s,t \rangle,p)$ accepts for all values of $p$.
- If $\langle G,s,t \rangle \notin \mathsf{!HAMPATH}$ then there exists a witness $p$ such that $!M(\langle G,s,t \rangle,p)$ rejects.

As you can see, $!M$ doesn't have the same promises regarding $\mathsf{!HAMPATH}$ that $M$ has regarding $\mathsf{HAMPATH}$.

Answer (score 0):

Nondeterministic can machines have multiple computation paths for each input. The machine accepts if at least one computation path accepts, regardless of how many reject.

So, consider a nondeterministic Turing machine $M$.

- If all paths on input $x$ accept, then $M$ accepts $x$.
- If some paths on input $y$ accept, and some reject, then $M$ accepts $y$.
- If all paths on input $z$ reject, then $M$ rejects $z$.

Now, suppose that we swap the accepting and rejecting states of $M$ to make a new machine, $M'$.

- All paths on input $x$ reject, so $M'$ rejects $x$.
- Some paths on input $y$ reject, and some accept, so $M'$ accepts $y$.
- All paths on input $z$ accept, so $M$ accepts $z$.

So we see that $M'$ doesn't accept the complement of the language accepted by $M$, since both machines accept $y$.